# Multiple static factory methods on java util.List interface

Tags: java, list, java-9

Why are there multiple `of` static factory methods in java util.List interface depending on the number of arguments, from 1 to 10? Was it not possible to have just one method that will take an array as input parameter?

Comment: Would you always want to create an array to initialize? If you already have an array you can use Arrays.asList

Comment: @CannedMoose I would expect to just have an interface method `of(args...)` since these static factory anyway call `ImmutableCollection` constructor which takes an `args..` input unless it has 2 or less parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer in [an article of Java World](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3164262/java-language/java-9s-other-new-enhancements-part-1.html) which seems pretty logical when you think about it.

> In each method list, the first method creates an empty unmodifiable collection. The next 10 methods create unmodifiable collections with up to 10 elements. **Despite their API clutter, these methods avoid the array allocation, initialization, and garbage collection overhead incurred by the final varargs method, which supports arbitrary-sized collections.**

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

they implemented 1 to 10 and >10, cause 1 to 10 are commonly used and offer a great deal of performance boost than using variable length of args input to the function e.g `args...`

Comment: There are 4 different implementations of `ImmutableCollections.List` depending on the number of arguments (0, 1, 2, n). Why not just have that one `of(args..)` method that will create different list based on the number of parameters? All those other static factory methods that take more than 2 parameters will use ListN. Correct?

Comment: I see your point now. Thanks you.